# Datatable: addColumn solo me envía texto del contenido HTML

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, laravel, datatables

Estoy haciendo el procesamiento por el servidor y añadiendo columnas por estilos CSS pero por alguna razón cuando envía esta columna, no es interpretada por `HTML` sino que solo es enviado como texto plano

Código PHP

```
 public function getCompras()
{
    $compra = Compra::with('empresas');
    return DataTables::of($compra)
        ->addColumn('empresas', function ($compra) {
            return $compra->empresas->first()->nombre;
        })
        ->addColumn('estado', function ($compra) {
            if ($compra->estado == 0) {
                return '<span class="label label-warning" >Pendiente</span>';
            } else {
                return '<span class="label label-success">Cobrado</span>';
            }
        })
        ->make(true);
}
```

Mi Js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#tb_por_pagar').DataTable({
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: '/cuentas/pagar/data',
    columns: [
      {data: 'factura_numero', name: 'factura_numero'},
      {data: 'total_transferencia', name: 'total_transferencia'},
      {data: 'fecha_pago', name: 'fecha_pago'},
      {data: 'empresas', name: 'empresas'},
      {data: 'estado', name: 'estado'},
    ],
    'language': {
      'url': '../plugins/dataTables.spanish.lang'
    }
  })
})
```

El resultado

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Laravel DataTables hace esto para prevenir los ataques `XSS` *(Cross-site scripting)* , si desea renderizar una columna con contenido HTML ,deberá recurir a [rawColumns(['colum','colum2'])](https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/7.0/raw-columns)

```
 return DataTables::of($compra)
    ->addColumn('empresas', function ($compra) {
        return $compra->empresas->first()->nombre;
    })
    ->addColumn('estado', function ($compra) {
        if ($compra->estado == 0) {
            return '<span class="label label-warning" >Pendiente</span>';
        } else {
            return '<span class="label label-success">Cobrado</span>';
        }
    })
    ->rawColumns(['estado'])
    ->make(true);
```