# como formatear html dentro de una funcion map() de php

Tags: php, html, laravel, datatables

tengo la siguiente función en un controlador de laravel

```
public function show()
{
    $organizaciones = Organizacion::with('estados')->selectRaw('distinct organizaciones.*');
    return  datatables()
            ->of($organizaciones)
            ->addColumn('estado', function (Organizacion $organizacion) {
               $estado =  $organizacion->estados()->orderBy("fecha_creado", "DESC")->take(1)->get();
                    return $estado->map(function ($estado) {
                       return '<a href="#" class="label labe-primary">'.$estado->estado.'</a>'; //como formatear el html ?
                    })->implode('<br>');
                })->editColumn('direccion', function ($dir) {
                return ucwords($dir->direccion);
            })->addColumn('action', function ($organizacion) {
                    $ruta = "organizaciones/";
                    $ficha = '<a href="#" onclick="ficha('.$organizacion->id.')" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_ficha" rel="tooltip" title="Ficha Empresa" class="btn btn-simple btn-primary btn-icon"><i class="material-icons">business</i></a>';
                    $historial = '<a href="#" onclick="historial_estados('.$organizacion->id.')" rel="tooltip" title="Historial de Estados" class="btn btn-simple btn-info btn-icon"><i class="material-icons">playlist_add</i></a>';
                    $cambiar_estado = '<a href="#" onclick="historial_estados('.$organizacion->id.')" rel="tooltip" title="Cambiar Estado" class="btn btn-simple btn-rose btn-icon"><i class="material-icons">low_priority</i></a>';
                    $editar = '<a href="#" onclick="organizacion_user('.$organizacion->id.',2)" rel="tooltip" title="Editar" class="btn btn-simple btn-success btn-icon edit"><i class="material-icons">edit</i></a>';
                    $eliminar = '<a href="#" onclick="eliminar('.$organizacion->id.',\''.$organizacion->nombre.'\',\''.$ruta.'\')" rel="tooltip" title="Eliminar" class="btn btn-simple btn-danger btn-icon"><i class="material-icons">close</i></a>';
                    return $ficha.$historial.$cambiar_estado.$editar.$eliminar;
                })
            ->toJson();
}
```

que da como resultado la siguiente tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como puedo formatear el html ?

gracias de antemano.

Comment: Esta pregunta ya se realizó [Aquí, puede revisar la respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/196915/datatable-addcolumn-solo-me-env%C3%ADa-texto-del-contenido-html/196930)

Comment: @Dev.Joel te agradezco por la respuesta, pude lograr formatear el html con ->rowColumn(['estado']). saludos.